# REF Error when using INDIRECT function to create dynamic row reference

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a matrix grid in "MasterSheetGrid". I have separate sheets that divide this info into certain dimensions, making it easier to handle for the user.

In order to make the file dynamic, i am trying to use INDIRECT Function within a function, to locate which row of the MasterSheetGrid to look for the information before returning.

The formula works when i specify the row manually, but using INDIRECT i receive a REF error, even though nothing is deleted.

Manual Formula `=INDEX(MasterSheetGrid!$5:$5,MATCH((XLOOKUP($J6,$5:$5,6:6)),MasterSheetGrid!6:6,0))`

Formula to locate the row
`=(MATCH($C6,MasterSheetGrid!$C:$C,0))`

Attempt to merge both using INDIRECT by referencing the cell where the above formula is stored, which results in REF
`INDEX(MasterSheetGrid!$5:$5,MATCH((XLOOKUP($J6,$5:$5,6:6)),(INDIRECT(J2:J2,0))))`

Ideally i would like to not have to use a cell to store the lookup row formula in, but i thought if i could create a correct formula with the cell reference, i could repeat for the formula.

Does anyone know what i am doing wrong?

[This is the view of the user. The formula would sit within column K](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KdQoG.jpg)

[This is the MasterSheetGrid view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vLzhX.png)

Comment: Could you also share what `MasterSheetGrid` would look like?

Comment: updated with the a screenshot of the MasterSheetGrid.

Comment: While your question is how to use INDIRECT. I recommend to use INDEX instead. INDIRECT is used if you want to dynamically refer to a sheet name typically. If you have a fixed sheet name you can better use non-volatile INDEX, for instance like `INDEX('MasterSheetGrid'!$1:$50,J6,)` (change `50` to the last row # in the tab)

Comment: Thanks foe your suggestion, would you be able to explain a little further, or provide more context on where that part of the formula would be inserted? As, I cannot see the relationship to find the correct row in the maturitysheetgrid

Comment: I ment `J2` instead of `J6`, so `=INDEX(MasterSheetGrid!$5:$5,MATCH((XLOOKUP($J6,$5:$5,6:6)),INDEX(MasterSheetGrid!$1:$50,J2,),0))` it references row 6 of that sheet in given example

Comment: I have just tried this at it worked! Thank you so much! If you leave an answer i will upvote :) I will now try to expand to remove the J2 reference and just use the formula

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `INDIRECT` which would cause recalculation at any change in the file, I recommend using `INDEX` instead. You refer to a fixed sheet name, therefore no need to use `INDIRECT`.

```
=INDEX(MasterSheetGrid!$5:$5,MATCH((XLOOKUP($J6,$5:$5,6:6)),INDEX(MasterSheetGrid!$1:$50,J2,),0))
```

Would be the equivalent of what you tried.

Proper use of `INDIRECT` would be:

```
=INDEX(MasterSheetGrid!$5:$5,MATCH((XLOOKUP($J6,$5:$5,6:6)),INDIRECT("MasterSheetGrid!"&J2&":"&J2),0))
```

And it's good practice to take the following into account (thanks David Leal):
If the Sheet name you're referring to contains one or more spaces you need to wrap the name in `'` like `'Sheet name'!`

Comment: I believe when the Sheet Name has spaces you cannot use this approach: `INDIRECT("Master SheetGrid!"&J2&":"&J2)` you get `#REF!`, but this works: `INDIRECT("'Master SheetGrid'!J2:J2")`

Comment: Nice addition added it in the answer

Answer (score 0):

To refer a range using `INDIRECT` you can use the following syntax (as a string delimited, for example delimited by `"`):

```
=INDIRECT("J2:J10")
```

for a cell, this works:

```
=INDIRECT(J2)
```

but if you try the same for a range:

```
=INDIRECT(J2:J10) -> #REF!
```

you get `#REF!`

If you are going to refer a Sheet from your Worksheet, then you need in all cases to enter the input argument as string:

```
=INDIRECT("Sheet1!A1:A10")
=INDIRECT("Sheet1!A1")
=INDIRECT("'Sheet 1'!A2") -> When Sheet Name has spaces use (') delimiter
```

**Notes**: By the way you are invoking `INDIRECT` using the second input argument (`a1`) which is optional with the value `0`. It is not required for getting a referring a range as I showed before.

I suspect this is the issue you are having

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I was storing the Row reference in J2, so i would still need to show the worksheet reference. How would i show this? INDIRECT (MasterSheetGrid""&J2&":"&J2&"")?

Comment: yes, for example this works: `=INDIRECT("Sheet1!A1:A1")`, but it would be enough: `=INDIRECT("Sheet1!A1")`, but you need to enter a string if you are going to refer to a Sheet.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I have just tried the follow `=INDEX(MasterSheetGrid!$5:$5,MATCH((XLOOKUP($J6,$5:$5,6:6)),INDIRECT("MasterSheetGrid!J2",0)))` but it still returned `#REF!`

Comment: then maybe you have another problem, without too much context it is difficult to help, if you are not providing a sample data (input/output) where we can reproducer you problem. Then please share a link to your excel file, so we can take a look to that real example, but better to provide a sample data, this is just a pan B.

Comment: would you try this please: `=INDEX(MasterSheetGrid!$5:$5,MATCH((XLOOKUP($J6,$5:$5,6:6)),INDIRECT("MasterSheetGrid!J2")))` without the second argument for `INDIRECT`.

Comment: you are using `$5`, `6:6` what is that syntax, did you forget the letters? I don-t think they are valid references.

Comment: I was referencing the rows 5:5 and 6:6, to ensure all columns were included. It is not best practice i assume, but can be cleaned up once the formula works (I hope)

Comment: @654lf456 please share a link to your file, it is difficult to follow or update your question with a sample data and expected output.

Comment: Hi David, thank you for all your help, it has been resolved now by another comment, but i really appreciate your help! Thank you for the info